# Would a plastic mask with openings below the chin prevent the aerosol to contaminate other persons?

Tags: flow, molecules

Would a plastic mask with openings below the chin prevent the aerosol to contaminate other persons if it is forced to go towards the floor? See picture please....EDIT--the opening could be covered with safety material(explaination for the question in my comment to the answer.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Such a shield falls into the "better than nothing" category. It stops you from exhaling directly towards other people, but doesn't stop your aerosols from mixing into the atmosphere.  It takes very little time for particles to distribute over long distances (think bacon smell from the kitchen reaching upstairs).
The reason to use a mouth&nose mask is to trap as much of the aerosol as possible in the mask material, thus reducing the atmospheric load.

Comment: Ok, material can be placed into the opening drawn in the picture...the main case for my question is that plastic is easier to clean after long period it has been placed on the mouth and nose an also plastic should be more resistent preventing a bunch of masks at home.....